# Calling LibreOffice from php exec on Mac using MAMP Pro

Tags: php, macos, pdf-generation, libreoffice, mamp-pro

ok so I have an application that I need to test locally using my MAMP Pro installation and LibreOffice (ver 4.4.1)

when I execute the following commands in terminal it works just fine:

```
cd /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS

./soffice --headless --convert-to pdf /Users/myusername/Sites/my-site/_plugins/site-pages/public/build-pages/temp/*.docx --outdir /Users/myusername/Sites/my-site/_plugins/site-pages/public/build-pages/temp
```

but when I try to replicate this in my php script like so:

```
$myCommand = '/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf /Users/myusername/Sites/my-site/_plugins/site-pages/public/build-pages/temp/*.docx --outdir /Users/myusername/Sites/my-site/_plugins/site-pages/public/build-pages/temp';

## create pdf's
exec($myCommand,$output);
foreach($output as $line){
print $line;
}
```

It doesn't work, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work' ? Any Errors ?

Comment: @JonasCz The page hangs and no pdf's are produced

Comment: Any errors in the logs ?

Comment: none that I can see, is there a specific log I should look at ?